# Take snapshot or screenshot while highligting the field in QTP during runtime

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to take screenshot of a field while highlighting that field during run time in QTP.

```
systemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--ignore-certificate-errors -incognito " & "www.google.com"

Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("Search").highlight

While Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("Search").highlight = True
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("Search").CaptureBitmap("C:\Google.bmp")
Wend
```

Thanks, any lead would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `Highlight` and `CaptureBitmap` methods are synchronous, this means that by the time the function returns the highlight operation/bitmap capturing have finished. In order to capture the flashing of the highlight you would need to create your own function that captures the screen a certain length of time after it has finished running, this will probably require multi-threading and isn't a good fit for VBScript.

Another thing you can do is tell UFT to capture a movie of the test run, this will include the highlighted object (you'll then have to manually find the spot in the clip and capture it).

See **Tools -> Options -> GUI Testing -> Screen Capture -> Save movie for results**.

Comment: Hi @Motti, Thanks for the response, could you please share the sample code for the above, if you have any. Thanks